# Интерфейсы и их реализация

Tags: c++, интерфейс

Не могу никак разобраться с интерфейсами и их реализацией. Обьясните пожалуйста как их правильно реализовывать и как это хотя-бы примерно делается в моем случае. 
 Дословно задание выглядит так
You have the following interface:

```
template<class T> 
class Stack 
{ 
public: 
Stack(); 
~Stack(); 
Stack( const Stack& ); 
Stack& operator=( const Stack& ); 
size_t Count() const; 
void Push( const T& ); 
T Рор(); // throws an exception if stack is empty 
private: 
//..... 
};
```

Please write a class which implements the interface by using std::vector or describe in detail how it can be done.

Comment: Тут очень важно не путать понятия интерфейса как абстрактного класса и интерфейса как списка отрытых методов класса. Эти абсолютно разные понятия называются одинаково. И самое смешное что и те и те имеют реализацию =). Например, то что в описании вашего тега, это скорее всего не то что вам нужно.

Comment: @mrFieldy, причем тут абстрактный класс?   Абстрактный класс обеспечивает интерфейс для своих  производных, поэтому может называться интерфейсным классом.  И что  с этого?... Интерфейс  понятие  независимое

Comment: @ARHovsepyan описание тега 'интерфейс' посмотрите. Это совсем не то что требуется автору вопроса, так?

Comment: @mrFieldy,  я говорю про ваш комментарий, а не о том, насколько правильно выражался автор вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Вам говорят, что скорее всего у Вас есть два варианта - отнаследоваться от этого класса и реализовать все его функции (но это маловероятно - виртуального деструктора нет и специально оставлена секция private, которой у интрефесов не должно быть).

Поэтому, скорее всего, нужно просто написать реализации функций.

```
template<class T> 
class Stack 
{ 
public: 
Stack(); 
~Stack(); 
Stack( const Stack& ); 
Stack& operator=( const Stack& ); 
size_t Count() const; 
void Push( const T& item); 
T Рор(); // throws an exception if stack is empty 
private: 
  std::vector<T> m_data; 
};
```

и дальше собственно реализации

```
size_t Stack::Count() const { return m_data.size(); }
void Stack::Push( const T& item) { m_data.push_back(item); }
```

и так далее...

Comment: только Pop()  удаляет элемент и обычно возвращает bool  или ничего не возвращает,  а для получения хвостового элемента нужно определять T& top()  и  const T& top() const

Comment: Это вопрос к тому, кто интерфейс придумывал.

Comment: я какраз добавил от себя именно для автора интерфейса

Comment: От автора до сих пор не поступило ни одного сообщения, уточнения.